# Currying operations in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, evaluation, metatable, meta-method

This question has some reference to the question [Defining logical operator implies in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394581/defining-logical-operator-implies-in-lua). The following code works fine.

```
local function _implies(a, b)
      if a == 1 and b == 0 then return 0 
        else return 1 end
    end
    
    local my_right = {
        __mul = function(self, b)
            return _implies(self.a, b)
        end
      }
      
      local _mt =  {
        __mul = function(a)
            return setmetatable({a=a}, my_right)
        end
    }
    
    local my_left={}
    setmetatable(my_left,_mt)
    imp = my_left
    local names={}
    
    
    for i = 0,1 do
       for j=0,1 do
         names.i=i;names.j=j
       print(i, j, names.i *imp* names.j)
      
       end
    end
```

The following code is similar to above code. It is for **logical and**. The question I want to ask is : Are both **and_left** and **and_right** are required in this case as well? Were they required  because **implies** is not commutative?  In other words, can the code be made somewhat efficient for defining **logand**?

```
    local function _and(a, b)
          if a == 1 and b == 1 then return 1 
            else return 0 end
    end
    
    local right_and = {
        __mul = function(self, b)
            return _and(self.a, b)
        end
      }
      
      local and_mt =  {
        __mul = function(a)
            return setmetatable({a=a}, right_and)
        end
    }
    
    local and_left={}
    setmetatable(and_left,and_mt)
   log_and = and_left
    local names={}
    
    
    for i = 0,1 do
       for j=0,1 do
 names.i=i;names.j=j
       print(i, j, names.i *log_and* names.j)
      
       end
end
```

Note: I know bitwise operator & is there but for some reasons, I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are both and_left and and_right are required

They were introduced because there are two semantically different multiplications involved.

But the code can be optimized.
The version below does not create a new table on every multiplication.
It also uses only one metatable instead of two.

```
do
   local function _implies(a, b)
      if a == 1 and b == 0 then
         return 0
      else
         return 1
      end
   end

   local temp, imp = {}, {}
   local _mt =  {
      __mul = function(a, b)
         if b == imp then
            temp[1] = a
            return temp
         elseif a == temp then
            return _implies(temp[1], b)
         end
      end
   }
   setmetatable(temp, _mt)
   setmetatable(imp, _mt)
   _G.imp = imp
end

local names={}
for i = 0, 1 do
   for j = 0, 1 do
      names.i=i
      names.j=j
      print(i, j, names.i *imp* names.j)
   end
end
```